# Should [query-execution-plans], [sql-execution-plan] and [query-plans] be synonymised?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

- [query-execution-plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-execution-plans)
- [sql-execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execution-plan)
- [query-plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-plans)

They all mean more or less the same. Shouldn't they be merged? Imho most suitable are short singular terms, since the propability that somebdy overlooks them and creates new ones is smaller. E.g. `query-plan` with `execution-plan` as alias.

Comment: Suggested title: "I plan to execute two of these tags. Any queries?".

Comment: The 2nd one says its specific to sql-server.

Comment: Then it should be called sql-server-execution-plan.

Comment: @Alohci IMO, that's what the sql-server tag would be for.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yes, maybe. I expect sql-server to be a much broader tag. Couldn't comment on whether execution plans for sql server alone deserve their own tag.

Comment: @Alohci I would think a post would use at least 2 tags, one to identify the database and a second to point to execution plan

Comment: @DanielA.White No, it isn't. SQL != SQL Server.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the tag description says it's specific to SQL Server

Comment: In SQL Server, there is a subtle difference between the terms "query plan" and "execution plan", as can be seen e.g. [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). In short, execution plan = query plan + execution context. (I myself didn't know that until recently.)

Comment: @AndriyM The distinction is far too subtle (and unknown to most) to be at all important for tagging purposes. The terms are used interchangeably throughout the documentation, and even internally.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the excerpt tag is ambiguous.

Answer (score 29):

On [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) we have [query-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-plan) (54 questions) as a synonym of [execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-plan) (197 questions). The product (e.g. [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)) and version are tagged separately.

On Stack Overflow, the breakdown is:

[query-execution-plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-execution-plans) (314 questions)
[sql-execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execution-plan) (140 questions)
[query-plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-plans) (109 questions)

All three essentially mean the same thing. My personal preference would be to have the same tags as dba.se so tags are preserved for migrations as much as possible.

**Proposal:** create a new master tag [execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-plan) and make all three existing tags synonyms, then merge.

Comment: And possibly add `query-plan` as another synonym?

Comment: on dba it makes sense to have `execution-plan` and it is easy to know it's about SQL (or maybe other DBs). But on stackoverflow things are not necessary specific to `DBs` thus it makes more sense to have `sql-execution-plan`.

Comment: @akostadinov Other question tags should make it clear whether it's a database question or not. On a quick search of SO, I couldn't find many instances of questions that would be tagged [execution-plan] that weren't database-related. So, I'm not sure the distinction you're concerned about actually exists.

Answer (score 4):

Paul, no-relation, White is on the right path with merging. I would contend for [sql-execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execution-plan) instead of [execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-plan).

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure I understand what you are proposing here. To merge all the tags under `sql-execution-plan` or what?  You might want to clarify this a bit.

Comment: @bluefeet It took a second but, unequivocally yes: he wants to make [tag:sql-execution-plan] the master tag instead of [tag:execution-plan].

Comment: @Daniel - Why?  Explain yourself!  If you're *contending*, then make your point.  Don't just leave us hanging :)

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and did a clean up of these tags this morning.  The main tag is now [sql-execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execution-plan) with the description no longer specifying SQL Server as the database this tag was for.  Then I made the following tags synonyms of it:

- [query-plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-plans)
- [explain-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain-plan)
- [query-execution-plans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-execution-plans)
- [query-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-plan)
- [execution-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-plan)